# Display last added item in ComboBox - Python

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a GUI with a tool button next to a Combobox. The tool button opens a directory browser to select a file and then adds that file Name to the Combobox drop-down list.

```
    def showFileOpenDialogLoad(self):
    """ Opens dialog to get Load file path """
    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',
                '/home')
    self.comboBoxFilePathLoad.addItem(filename)
```

This works perfectly, however, I then want the Combobox to directly display the last added filename. I have tried using `.insertItem(0,filename)`instead and then setting `self.comboBoxFilePathLoad.currentIndex = -1`but it still displays the first added filename even though in the Dropdown list the last added filename is now above the old and displayed one. Apparently in C# you would use `cmbBox.SelectedIndex = cmbBox.Items.count -1` but Pyqt does not have a `SelectedIndex`method.

This does not seem like such a difficult question but somehow I can not find a solution to it online... The [QComboBox Class Reference](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html) does not explain `count` and `CurrentIndex` either. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried [setCurrentIndex](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html#setCurrentIndex)?

Comment: Something like `self.comboBoxFilePathLoad.setCurrentIndex( self.comboBoxFilePathLoad.count() - 1 )` would do the trick.